# Saving list items in Entity Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to save a list of items in **Configuration** entity. But when the model's **addItem()** function gets called the **this.getItems()** is going to be **NULL**. I dont understand why... What is the best approach to save an object nd it's items in the same request?

*Configuration.java*

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Configuration extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    private CarModel carModel;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<EquipmentItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(EquipmentItem equipmentItem){

        this.getItems().add(equipmentItem);
    }
}
```

*ConfigurationServiceImpl.java*

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationService{

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationRepository configurationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EquipmentItemRepository equipmentItemRepository;

    @Override
    public ConfigurationDTO save(ConfigurationDTO configurationDTO) {
        Configuration configuration = Configuration.builder()
                .name(configurationDTO.getName())
                .build();

        for (EquipmentItemDTO item: configurationDTO.getItems()) {
            configuration.addItem(equipmentItemRepository.findById(item.getId())
                    .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new));
        }

        configurationRepository.save(configuration);
        return DTOConverter.convertConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, this issue is with @SuperBuilder annotation, do you really need that? can't work with @Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is assigned to null because of @SuperBuilder annotation, because it will ignore the initialized value if it is not annotated with @Builder.Default like below

```
Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Configuration extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    private CarModel carModel;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;

    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<EquipmentItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(EquipmentItem equipmentItem){

        this.getItems().add(equipmentItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use @SuperBuilder annotation because of inheritance.